# How can I get access to Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook.OlRuletype (or other namespaces) in WSH, JScript

Tags: office-interop, jscript, wsh

I have written the WSH script using JScript. I am currently getting in stuck that I cannot refer to the namespace "Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook.OlRuletype". The source code is shown below:

```
var olApp = WScript.CreateObject("Outlook.Application");
var olNS = olApp.Session;
var folder = olNS.Folders("myname@mailserv.com").Folders("Inbox");

CreateRule(olNS);
ShowInbox(folder);

function CreateRule(olNS)
{
    var rules = olNS.DefaultStore.GetRules();

    //Error occurred here..
    //Error:  'Microsoft' is undefined
    //Code:   800A1391
    //Source: Microsoft JScript runtime error
    var opt = Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook.OlRuletype.olRuleReceive;

    var newRule = rules.Create("Testing", opt);
}

function ShowInbox(folder)
{
    if (olApp.Explorers.Count == 0)
    {
        folder.Display();
    }
}
```

Am I correctly referring to the namespace? Thank you for every suggestion in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Windows Script Host and JScript don't know anything about constants in type library enumerations. You need to explicitly define these constants in your script:

```js
var olRuleReceive = 0;
var olRuleSend = 1;
```

> So, have I need to find out about the number of constant value myself? Do you have some way to search that value from MSDN document?

You have several options:

- Look up the constant values in the [Outlook developer reference](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff860961.aspx) in MSDN.
- Look up the constant values in the VBA Object Browser (see [Bill_Stewart's comment](https://stackoverflow.com/q/21929876/113116#comment33474773_21990245)).
- Place your code into a [Windows Script File (.wsf)](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows_Script_File) and import the Outlook type library [using the <reference> element](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows_Script_File#Exposing_constants). In this case you can use all Outlook enumeration constants without having to declare them.

  ```xml
  <job>
      <reference object="Outlook.Application"/>
      <script language="JScript">
          WScript.Echo(olRuleSend); // 1
      </script>
  </job>
  ```

Comment: So, have I need to find out about the number of constant value myself? Do you have some way to search that value from MSDN document? Is it sorted starting from 0 and so on?

Comment: Probably the quickest way to find out the value of an enumeration is: 1) Open the office application; 2) Press Alt+F11 to access VBA; 3) Press F2 to view object browser; and 4) search for the enumeration constant.